# Is there a significant cost of Beginning & Committing a MySQL Transaction even if no changes made to tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, transactions

This application is running on AWS EC2, using RDS/MySQL (5.7).

We have an audit script that is visiting every user in a MySQL user's table. \

For each user, we

- Unconditionally start a transaction,
- Possibly make some changes the user's record and to other tables.
- Unconditionally commit the transaction.

Now, it's likely (and common) in step 2 that no changes were made to any table. The question arose during the code inspection as to the performance impact of Starting/Committing a transaction for many records when no changes were made.

I've read elsewhere that MySQL is optimized for commits, not rollback. But I've yet to find a discussion on the cost of starting/committing transactions when no work was done.

Comment: What is the ping time between your client and the AWS server?

Comment: I presume you mean between the EC2 instance and our RDS/MySQL Instance.  Unfortunately, the AWS/RDS nodes do not support ping for inbound IP rules.  However, I believe the ping time is very low because when I did my simple test (noted below), it took a mere 5 seconds for 10K begins/commits in a tight loop. 

When I ran the same test from my PC to RDS, the time was pitiful. But that was on home wifi through VPN software, etc.  Really an invalid test for my use case.

Comment: Are you answering your own question -- 0.5ms?  It is OK to "self-answer" your question.  I suggest you do so.

Answer (score 4):

There's no significant cost in short running transactions.

The minimal cost of transactions starts to happen when changes are actually made.

Rollbacks are only expensive if there is data to be changed during the rollback, otherwise its a fairly empty operation.

Committing (and probably rollback) where there are no changes shouldn't incur a penalty.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that as soon as you read an InnoDB table, whether you explicitly "started a transaction" or not, InnoDB does similar work.

The alternative to starting a transaction is relying on *autocommit*. But autocommit doesn't mean *no transaction happens*. Autocommit means the transaction starts implicitly when your query touches an InnoDB table, and the transaction commits automatically as soon as the query is done. You can't run more than one statement, and you can't rollback, but otherwise it's the same as an explicit transaction.

You don't really save anything by trying to avoid starting a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is most definitely an overhead, and it can be quite significant. I recently worked with a client who had exactly this issue (lots of empty commits due to a bug in their ORM) and their database was burning through about 30% of CPU on empty commits.

Capture a day of slow log with long_query_time=0 (important!), put it through mysqldumpslow or pt-query-digest, and see if you have a query that is just `COMMIT;` using up a large amount of CPU.

Comment: I did a little test on the EC2 instance.  10k Begins/commits with no table updates consistently takes 5 to 6 seconds. This is a php client. When I added a table update as part of each TXN, that same 10k loop took about 30sec.   So, it’s not insignificant, but for my application and the expected number of records, I can live with the 5 to 6 seconds penalty.

Comment: The thing you need to consider is whether the CPU time that consumes would be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: So, 3ms for a 1-update transaction?  That seems a bit high, assuming SSDs and only "one" I/O.  (However, I think AWS makes 6 copies.)

Comment: @RickJames I think you are referring to Aurora with the "6 copies". It doesn't apply to regular RDS.